# Search Keyword Query - Site URL with space in Path not working

Tags: search, search-results, keywordquery, path, keyword-query-language

I have tried to search for specific site using following simple **Keyword Query**:

`Path:https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Test site 1/ FileType:doc*`

Above query is not working due to space contains in the site URL.

Following works as it does not contains space in the path:

`Path:https://contoso.sharepoint.com/TestSite1/ FileType:doc*`

I have tried with Path parameter in quotations. It does not work & returns zero results.

**Following does not work:**

- `Path:'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Test site 1/' FileType:doc*`
- `Path:"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Test site 1/" FileType:doc*`
- `Path:https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Test%20site%201/ FileType:doc*`

Any solution to search using keyword query for specific site with site url contains space ?

Answer (score 5):

Find the solution. Use the `Site` in place of `Path`:

```
Site:"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Test site 1/" FileType:doc*
```

[Searchable site properties](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyword-queries-and-search-conditions-for-Content-Search-c4639c2e-7223-4302-8e0d-b6e10f1c3be3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#siteproperties)

Comment: what's the syntax if you want to search for two path (two SharePoint site)?

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried with search result source. Please create a search result source and try out it will work even if you have space in the url.

Check this link for your reference. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx

Comment: I have tried it. It was not working.